# Freeze date function for various dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to write a formula in excel that will continue to update the date in specified cells to =today() when the client is listed as active, but as soon as the client turns inactive, it will freeze on that date. Here is my thought written out: =IF(A=active, =today(), date that A was changed to inactive). Could someone help me write this out in excel?

Thanks!

Comment: This cannot be done with formula, outside of using and allowing a circular reference(which is very problematic, and requires the change of settings on regular basis).  It will need vba in a Worksheet_Change event.

Comment: Inside if() you only need today() without the =.